# How do I sort a GeoJSON features array by a property value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, geojson

I am looking to sort a GeoJSON file on a property so I can then slice it keeping only the top 5 features. So for example I wish to take this [GeoJSON](https://github.com/timwis/leaflet-choropleth/blob/gh-pages/examples/basic/crimes_by_district.geojson) and sort the file in descending order by the incidents property:

```
...
     [
                -75.1972382872565,
                39.9294288475177
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "area": "",
        "location": "24th St. & Wolf St.",
        "perimeter": "81903.64182498",
        "dist_numc": "01",
        "sum_area": "",
        "area_sqmi": "216350124.153",
        "district_i": "",
        "objectid": "321",
        "globalid": "c040618c-ac93-4b22-b174-0ea08e0f805d",
        "district_": "1",
        "_feature_id": "1",
        "_feature_id_string": "Police_Districts.1",
        "dist_num": "1",
        "div_code": "SPD",
        "phone": "686-3010",
        "incidents": 11553
      }
    },
...
```

I'm looking to basically rearrange the order of the features array so that it's in descending order and the highest incident features are first.

How would I go about this? I am used to creating a compare function and then sorting an array with something like this:

```
//FUNCTION: SORT
 export const compare = ( a, b ) => {
    if ( a.incidents < b.incidents ){
      return -1;
    }
    if ( a.incidents > b.incidents ){
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

But in this case I need to sort a JSON and only sort an array inside of it so I am unsure how to proceed.

I set up an example where i attempt to sort via a button click but doesn't seem to be working:

https://codesandbox.io/s/slicing-geojson-qg1hb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Geojson is still valid json, so you could sort this like any other plain old JavaScript object. Geojson just defines a schema, not a new type.

Comment: Attempted in an example above but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @LoF10, has the answer helped you?

Answer (score 2):

Consider this file as JSON. To do that, I've copied the first three data from that `geojson` file and store into a variable called `data`. So we need to sort that array according to the `incidents` property. Now execute javascript's [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function to `data.features`. Since your data is big and you're sorting the data according to the `incidents` property, make sure to print only `incidents` property to see whether your data is being sorted or not. As StackOverflow asks limited characters(30000) in this section, I'm going to keep only the first three coordinates from every `geometry` property. Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
var data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                -75.0544420852857,
                                40.044532749252
                            ],
                            [
                                -75.054816199384,
                                40.0441717116827
                            ],
                            [
                                -75.0551367855513,
                                40.0438732632911
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "area": "",
                "location": "Harbison Ave. & Levick St.",
                "perimeter": "63587.3693993",
                "dist_numc": "02",
                "sum_area": "",
                "area_sqmi": "192346097.032",
                "district_i": "",
                "objectid": "322",
                "globalid": "95200c4a-2617-47c2-93f1-07d6359a92e9",
                "district_": "2",
                "_feature_id": "2",
                "_feature_id_string": "Police_Districts.2",
                "dist_num": "2",
                "div_code": "NEPD",
                "phone": "686-3020",
                "incidents": 32340
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                -75.1972382872565,
                                39.9294288475177
                            ],
                            [
                                -75.1969248893574,
                                39.9291749499585
                            ],
                            [
                                -75.1966534158686,
                                39.9293232425744
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "area": "",
                "location": "24th St. & Wolf St.",
                "perimeter": "81903.64182498",
                "dist_numc": "01",
                "sum_area": "",
                "area_sqmi": "216350124.153",
                "district_i": "",
                "objectid": "321",
                "globalid": "c040618c-ac93-4b22-b174-0ea08e0f805d",
                "district_": "1",
                "_feature_id": "1",
                "_feature_id_string": "Police_Districts.1",
                "dist_num": "1",
                "div_code": "SPD",
                "phone": "686-3010",
                "incidents": 11553
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                -75.1343640909741,
                                39.9529315410666
                            ],
                            [
                                -75.1352375679666,
                                39.9506957263754
                            ],
                            [
                                -75.1352409996735,
                                39.9506869425429
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "area": "",
                "location": "11th St. & Winter St.",
                "perimeter": "34655.32085552",
                "dist_numc": "06",
                "sum_area": "",
                "area_sqmi": "69279267.8986235",
                "district_i": "",
                "objectid": "325",
                "globalid": "e0afa680-ecd3-470e-b0f8-59b70d4f72b5",
                "district_": "6",
                "_feature_id": "5",
                "_feature_id_string": "Police_Districts.5",
                "dist_num": "6",
                "div_code": "CPD",
                "phone": "686-3060",
                "incidents": 23428
            }
        }
    ]
};

console.log("Before sorting");
console.log(data.features[0].properties.incidents);
console.log(data.features[1].properties.incidents);
console.log(data.features[2].properties.incidents);

data.features.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.properties.incidents < b.properties.incidents)
        return -1;
    else if (a.properties.incidents > b.properties.incidents)
        return 1;
});

console.log("After sorting");
console.log(data.features[0].properties.incidents);
console.log(data.features[1].properties.incidents);
console.log(data.features[2].properties.incidents);
```